# Auto Scroll of the GridView

Tags: android

I have got a requirement for my app and the requirement states that:

When the `View` of the `GridView` is filled and when the `view` moves down then the vertical scroll should scroll down automatically to show up the newly loaded images. 
I tried using:

```
gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(position); 
gridView.setSelection(position);
```

But on using them my app is crashing. How to enable auto vertical scroll for a `GridView`? Help me out!!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use Instrumentation Library to scroll a gridview. It provides you with TouchUtils where you can override the drag function and perform a scroll on the view. Robotium is a free library that is available which is designed specially for this purpose.

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/

Refer the link along with thier tutorials. Once u get your hands dirty, you can take it to the next level. Also many people use robotium so you will find lots of resources to guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. As I am a newbie in Android am not at all aware of Instrumentation Library. Can you please provide me some source for that? Thanks

Comment: Will provide you something by Monday :)